# Sum digits of numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Trying to write a function that takes a list like:

```
x = [1, 13, 14, 9, 8]
```

for example and sums the digits like:

```
1 + (1+3) + (1+4) + 9 + 8 = 27
```

What I have attempted thus far:

```
def sum_d(x):
    if not x:
        return 0
    else:
        return x[0] + sum_d(x[1:])
```

Comment: Turn them first to strings then sum each digits.

Comment: @ingrosso Can it be that some of the elements in the list are negative? If so, how would you break let's say -14 up? -1 - 4 ?

Comment: I want the input to be written like sum_d([1, 3, 15]) and the output like: 10
It doesnt need to handle negative numbers, only integers from >= 0

Comment: @ingrosso Then it will work fine for you. just rename the function if the name is important.

Answer (score 6):

How about this beauty:

```
the_sum = sum(int(char) for n in x for char in str(n))
print(the_sum)  # prints -> 27
```

What is happening here is that i am going through all elements of the list one by one (`for n in x`), i convert them to strings to be able to iterate through each character by character (`for char in str(n)`) and finally sum all the generated numbers after converting them back to integers (`int(char)`)

---

You can easily convert the above into a function like so:

```
def sum_of_characters(my_list):
    return sum(int(char) for n in my_list for char in str(n))
```

---

### **NOTE**

As @Jim noticed, the proposed solution here cannot handle negative numbers in the list. Modifying it so that it doesn't throw an error can be done by checking to make sure `char` is a digit and not a sign:

```
def sum_of_characters(my_list):
    return sum(int(char) for n in my_list for char in str(n) if char.isdigit())
```

Making it work though while at the same time keeping it as a single generator expression is quite a task..

---

Just for the record, an other variant that just uses a generator expression and can handle negative numbers that are either < 10 or would break up like so: -14 -> -1 **+** 4 is this:

```
def sum_of_characters(my_list):
    return eval('+'.join(str(char) for n in x for char in str(n)))
```

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't handle negative numbers but we can't know what OP was after because nothing was specified.

Comment: @Jim Nicely caught Jim. It might be difficult to go forth with nothing but a generator that handles negative numbers as well but i am trying.

Comment: You've got my upvote for the attempt. You're unfortunately plagued by OPs vague description of his issue, don't worry about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification, and your original code will work :

```
def sum_d(x):
    x = str(x)
    if len(x) == 1:
        return int(x)
    else:
        return int(x[0]) + sum_d(int(x[1:]))
```

also possible in single line :

```
sum(int(y) for y in (chain(*[str(x) for x in [1, 13, 14, 9, 8]])))
```

Explained here :

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [str(x) for x in [1, 13, 14, 9, 8]]
['1', '13', '14', '9', '8']
>>> chain(*[str(x) for x in [1, 13, 14, 9, 8]])
<itertools.chain object at 0x7feadcd067d0>
>>> list(chain(*[str(x) for x in [1, 13, 14, 9, 8]]))
['1', '1', '3', '1', '4', '9', '8']
>>> sum(int(y) for y in (chain(*[str(x) for x in [1, 13, 14, 9, 8]])))
27
```

Comment: Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
sorry im new to this

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,13,14,9,8]
number = 0
for element in x:
    my_string = str(element)
    for i in range(len(my_string)):
        number += int(my_string[i])
print(number)
```

This will do it, there might be a way to slice ints that doesn't involve converting them to strings though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumx(x):
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        if(x[i]>10):
            sum=0
            while(x[i]>0):
                sum+=x[i]%10
                x[i]=x[i]/10
            x[i]=sum
    print(x)
>>> sumx(x)
[5, 4, 5, 9, 8]
```